# height should be of fixed size in responsive chart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I have a responsive chart, but i want the height to be fixed and only width size should change with change in screen size. Is there a way to do that?

```
height = 200px;    
d3.select(divId).selectAll("svg")
                    .datum(cData)
                    .transition().duration(500)
                    .call(chart).attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width to a percentage value!

Let's say you want the width of the chart to always be 50% of the viewable area...you'd set html to width: 100%, and #chart (or whatever) to width: 50%.

Comment: width resize is already working. viewbox attr takes care of that. how do i make height fixed?

Comment: This could be complete crap because I'm not really familiar with d3.js, but if you have the script in the DOM, try putting it in a div and then using css to fix the height?

Comment: that doesnt work. I am looking to specifically make just width responsive